# Two If Statements with a Logical Operator

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
fhand=open('mbox-short.txt')
count=0
for line in fhand:
    words=line.split()
    print(words)
    if len(words)==0: continue
    if words[0]!='From': continue
    print(words[2])
```

This code prints a valid output (I am trying to get the day of a sent email from a mbox.txt file). When I try to combine the two "if" statements as follows:

```
if words[0]!='From' and len(words)==0: continue
```

I get this error:

```
['From', 'stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za', 'Sat', 'Jan', '5', '09:14:16', '2008']
Sat
['Return-Path:', '<postmaster@collab.sakaiproject.org>']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(words[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I see that the issue occurs at the Return-Path line but why is it taken into consideration? And shouldn't the combined if statement have the same output as the two separated if statements?

Comment: If one ***or*** the other condition is true, you want to `continue`. Not only if *both* are true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is that you flipped the order of your tests. You're now testing the length *after* attempting to check what the first value is:

```
if words[0]!='From' and len(words)==0: continue
```

Python checks conditions from left to right, so it will first check `if words[0]!='From'` and then test `len(words)==0`, however if `words` is empty then the first test tries to access a non existent index and creates your error.

You need to use this order instead and use the `or` operator as deceze pointed out, because you only care if *one* of these is `True`, not both.

```
if len(words)==0 or words[0]!='From': continue
```

Answer (score 2):

The differing output shows that the two solutions are not equivalent: you chose the wrong operator.

What happens in the original? If the fist condition is met, `continue` is executed. If not, the second one is tested and the loop `continue`d as appropriate.

This behaviour is relicated by one operator. but this is the `or` operator. And if you do it in the right order, everthing works as wanted:

```
if len(words)==0 or words[0]!='From': continue
```

Let's look what happens: the first part of the condition is executed. If `len(words)==0` is true, the second half is skipped (this is called short-circuiting) and the loop `continue`d. This is good, as `words[0]` would lead to an error if evaluated despite the length being 0.

Only if the length is *not* 0, the second test is performed.

Note that there are several ways of testing a list for emptiness:

- `len(words) == 0`
- `not len(words)`
- `not words`

Both of these expressions are `True` if the list is empty and `False` if not.

Comment: ...although the Pythonic way would be to say `if not words or words[0] != 'From':`... or maybe, for clarification, `if (not words) or words[0] != 'From':`